# Clipboardy chrome extension to copy posted source to clipboard

Tags: script, chrome-extensions, google-chrome, open-source

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

[Clipboardy](http://rainsoft.io/clipboardy-chrome-extension/) is a Chrome extension for copying posted code to clipboard from stackoverflow.com, github.com & npmjs.com. It can:

- Copy the source code to clipboard with just one click
- Select the source text
- Collapse the source text
- Show the history of clipboard usage
- Configurable toolbar

#### License

Under MIT license. The app is open source, the repository is [here](https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy).

#### Download

[Install](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clipboardy/gkafpbdjggkmmngaamlghmigadfaalhc) the extension using chrome store.
[Read](http://rainsoft.io/clipboardy-chrome-extension/) the full list of features & tips.
[Contribute](https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy) to project with pull requests and bug reports.

#### Platform

The application is an extension for Google Chrome browser.
It works on OS X, Windows and Linux.

### Contact

The author is [Dmitri Pavlutin](http://rainsoft.io/about-me/).
Please contact me [here](http://rainsoft.io/contact-me/).

### Code

The extension is coded in JavaScript, based on AngularJS library.
Gulp is used for tasks automation.

Don't hesitate to write feedback or suggest some ideas.

Comment: Something about this extension interacts very poorly with the inline code editor on GitHub, to the point where GitHub's editor can sometimes become unusable. For example, compare the performance of https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/edit/master/blacklisted_websites.txt (attempt to add one line to the end of the file) with and without the extension enabled. Also, the extension probably shouldn't be doing any processing on sites outside of SE sites at all, really.